# Where is ttylinux's source code?

Tags: linux

I can not find ttylinux's source code anywhere. I tried googling with d/t keywords but no luck. So can anyone point me to a working link that i can download the source from, please?

Answer (score 4):

According to `whois`, the domain `ttylinux.net` expired in October, and appears to be defunct:

```
Domain Name: TTYLINUX.NET
Registrar: DNC HOLDINGS, INC.      
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 291
Whois Server: whois.directnic.com
Referral URL: http://www.directnic.com
Name Server: EXPIRED-DOMAIN-NS50.DIRECTNIC.COM
Name Server: EXPIRED-DOMAIN-NS51.DIRECTNIC.COM
Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProh>
Status: redemptionPeriod http://www.icann.org/epp#redemptionPeriod
Updated Date: 19-nov-2015
Creation Date: 08-oct-2008        
Expiration Date: 08-oct-2015
```

See *[TTYLinux end is near and looking for maintainer(s)](http://www.linuxtoday.com/it_management/ttylinux-end-is-near-and-looking-for-maintainers-150911041513.html)* on LinuxToday.

Answer (score 2):

The source code ISO that you can get via the Internet Archive is the collection of source code packages that were used to build ttylinux, with any patches. It will be hard to figure what you can do with that source code; there is no description of how to build it for ttylinux. Also, it probably does not have the init scripts that startup the ttylinux system.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Internet Archive, e.g., searching for ["ttylinux.net"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150701000000*/http://ttylinux.net)

You can even grab e.g.,
ttylinux-pc_i686-2015.02-src.iso.gz from there.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the code is now in https://github.com/JessiHash/crosslinux

I found a link to an archived page of ttylinux here: http://linux.wikia.com/wiki/Ttylinux As you can see there, it shows a git repository which no longer exists. However, the person that commited to the git repo is the same guy that according to a brief research was the original maintainer of ttylinux, Douglas Jerome.